Server SSL connection to Helix Core Digital Ocean droplet keeps dropping/timing out
I've created a Perforce Helix Core droplet on Digital Ocean and have been able to use it successfully. However, after a while, the connection eventually drops and I am unable to connect. I get errors such as these:


I tried opening adding inbound and outbound rules for port 1666 on my computer to see if that fixes it, but the issue persists.


I think it's a local machine issue, because every now and then, like after a reboot, I can once again connect and use Perforce fine for a while. The Digital Ocean droplet seems fine as well.

The issue was caused by the droplet not having enough RAM. I had set up the droplet to run on 1 GB of memory, the cheapest plan.
Bumping up the memory to 2 GB seems to have fixed the problem.
